# Sum of elements with a loop

Tags: matlab

I have to calculate the sum of a vector

```
v = [5 2 6 8 1 2];
```

by using a loop. I have tried this

```
v = [5 2 6 8 1 2];
i = 0;

for i = 1:6
v1 = sum(v(i)) 
i = i + 1;
end
```

But I cant get it to work. It to choose the first vector and then add it to the second.

Comment: write it: sum(v)

Comment: You don't need `i = 0` or to increment `i` within the loop, this is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = [5 2 6 8 1 2];
sumValue = 0;
for vals = 1:length(v)
    sumValue = sumValue + v(vals);
end
disp(sumValue)
```